# Any body knows the name of the product $A\circ B$, It is not Hadamard tensor product

Tags: vectorization

I have seen this operation in a vectorization operation of $D=AX^{T}B$ i.e. $vec(D)=\left( A\circ B\right) vec(X),$
\begin{equation*}
A\circ B=
\begin{pmatrix}
A_{1}B_{1}^{T} & A_{2}B_{1}^{T} & \cdots & A_{n}B_{1}^{T} \\ 
A_{1}B_{2}^{T} & A_{2}B_{2}^{T} & \cdots & A_{n}B_{2}^{T} \\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 
A_{1}B_{n}^{T} & A_{2}B_{n}^{T} & \cdots & A_{n}B_{n}^{T}
\end{pmatrix},
\end{equation*}
where $A_{j}$, $B_{j}$, $j=1,2,\cdots ,N,$ denoting the column vector of $A$ and $B,$ respectively.

Comment: Where have you seen this? I can't see what it accomplishes that cannot be done just as well by the Kronecker product and a commutation matrix.

Comment: I have seen this in this work https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=1529639, I have tried with Kronecker product but it did not work for me.

Comment: Quite interesting. They introduce it in the paragraph between equation (11) and equation (12), but they don't mention any name or reference for it. As I said before, it seems somewhat pointless, as $(A\circ B)=(A\otimes B)K^\top$ for a suitable [commutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix) $K$.

Comment: You are right, this solves my question, thanks for the observation. Now I have to compute which form has the commutation matrix K.